# how to execute mount_smbfs terminal command to mount

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, terminal, mount

I mounted the hard drive by using the GUI in Mac.

However, I want to mount the hard drive by using the terminal commands.

How can I execute a terminal command `mount_smbfs` from my Objective-C Cocoa application?

```
NSTask* task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/sbin/mount_smbfs"];
[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"//user:50000@smb://192.168.2.1/Share",@"Volumes/C$/upload", nil]];
[task launch];
```

Here is my edited with my code Could you please help me?

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the call to `mount_smbfs` in [`NSTask`](https://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to execute it from your Obj-C program:

```
NSTask* task = [NSTask new];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/sbin/mount_smbfs"];
[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"//myUser:myPassword@SERVER/share", @"mountPath", nil]];
```

In setArguments you provide an array with at least 2 elements: the path to the share, and the mount point.

Also check `man mount_smbfs` for more argument options.

Comment: Sorry but I am new in objective C how can I execute it? When I google it I found mount_smbfs will mount the hard drive by using NSTask.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. What is wrong with my code shown below.In addition what does argument mean and stand for?

 
`[task setLaunchPath:@"/Volumes/volume_name/folder_name"];`

Comment: thank you but I am still have no idea about the setting the arguments and where is the mounted hard drive in the code?

Comment: I added more detail about the arguments. `launchPath` is the path to `mount_smbfs` executable; `/Volumes/volume_name/folder_name` seems more of a mount point...

Comment: So how can I adjust the mount point? Should not I adjust a mount point to see where to copy the file?

Comment: the second element in the array you pass in with `setArguments` is your mount point...

Comment: finally I would like to learn the myUser and pass should be defined as a string at the begining am I right?

Comment: what is the problem you are having? have you substituted your actual username/password/server address/mount point for the placeholders I put in my answer? if you are not getting connected, review your server log, or try with a smb server you can set for anonyous access to troubleshoot issue more easily...

Comment: yes I put all my crendentials in place but there is no connection to my server. Should I run the task? I edited my code.

Comment: after I put launch, I am getting an error "could not find mount point /Volumes/C$/upload".

Comment: yes, `mount_smbfs` requires administrator privileges. see: http://sveinbjorn.org/STPrivilegedTask, a NSTask replacement; or read http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html for the full story.

Comment: the mount point is the directory in which the file is copied. Isnt it? If it is so, how is it possible to not find the mount point? Also, by using gui I copied to this directory and I was successful.

Comment: the mount point must exist before mounting, usually. possibly the gui does some trick...

Comment: the point is already created before mounting. do you have any suggestion?

Comment: really no idea, but shouldn't `@"Volumes/C$/upload"` be `@"/Volumes/C$/upload"`?

Comment: I am getting the authentication error "server rejected the connection"

Comment: would you try with: `arrayWithObjects:@"//user:50000@192.168.2.1/Share"` -- I have no idea what the authentication error might be. you should possibly check some long on the server side...

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler to do this with AppleScript:

```
- (BOOL) mount {
    NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:
                             @"tell application \"Finder\"\n"
                             "  mount volume \"smb://server.domain/SomeMountPoint\"\n"
                             "end tell"];
    if (!script) {
        NSLog(@"Error creating AppleScript object");
        return NO;
    }

    NSDictionary *errorMessage = nil;
    NSAppleEventDescriptor *result = [script executeAndReturnError:&errorMessage];
    return (BOOL)result;
}
```

There are some limitations:

1. You have to use `NSAppleScript` on the main thread.
2. Your application won't respond to any events while Finder tries to mount the volume.
3. If mounting fails, you don't have any control over how Finder presents the error message.